# Unable to Use python-pip command on Linux Manjaro

Tags: python-3.x, pip, archlinux, manjaro, archlinux-arm

So I recently just bought a Raspberry Pi 4, flashed Linux Manjaro XFCE onto it and booted it up. I managed to install `python-pip` with Pacman without any errors but when I actually try to use the command, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==20.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')())
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 504, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 177, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: pip
```

I've tried reinstalling it many times but it still doesn't work. This is what comes out while I install it.

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) python-pip-20.3.4-1

Total Installed Size:  1.60 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                     [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                   [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                        [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                  [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                [####################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) installing python-pip                                                                                        [####################################################################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
```

Do take note that I'm a complete Linux noob and have recently just started using it.

One more thing to add, I already have Python installed on this and its version is Python 3.8.5. Just in case anyone needs that information.

Comment: What happens when you run `pip` in terminal?

Comment: I get the error shown in my post. importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError @T0ny1234

Comment: what about `pip3` ? When you run it you should see the man page of pip.

Comment: Same thing, same error

Comment: Can you write the exact command you are trying to start pip with?

Comment: pip install pygame, pip install virtualenv

Comment: for creating virtual environmet you can do `python -m venv venv` in your working folder, and then `cd` in that directory, if you are not in it already, then do  `source venv\bin\activate` (this activates the virtual environment), and finaly do `pip install pygame`, btw if you want to install more modules with pip you do `pip install pygame virtualenv`

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. Why though? Does that mean I will never be able to install packages globally? :(

Comment: You will, your install command is wrong -  basically here `pip install pygame, pip install virtualenv` you are trying to install pip with pip. Do you want me to add this as an answer?

Comment: Oh but, I did use the proper install command. I was just listing out the two separate commands that I tried. I used those commands separately. Without being in a virtualenv, I used `pip install pygame`, and then tried `pip install virtualenv`. But those didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235129/discussion-between-t0ny1234-and-daniel-tam).

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -m pip install pygame`? Does that work? If it does it just means you need to configure your `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a related issue today without finding a good description about how to recover from such situation. Soo… Here's a "porr man's" solution to that:

```
pamac reinstall python-pip
```

If that's not enough and you have accidentally removed some or all of Manjaro's system Python packages, reinstall them one by one:

```
pamac reinstall python-<MISSING-MODULE>
```

Example:
pamac reinstall python-pip python-packaging python-chardet python-urllib3 …

If even pamac is not available, replace the command with pacman:

```
sudo pacman -S python-<module-name>
```

If someone finds a better way, please share! Happy trouble-shooting! :)